# How to use SqlBuilder

Tags: c#, dapper, sqlbuilder

This SqlBuilder:

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder(); 
var sql = builder.AddTemplate( /*...
```

Intensely dumb question but, how do I use this? I know it's in `Dapper.Contrib`, but that `using` statement isn't enough. What references or other `using` statements do I need to add?

Comment: An alternative way is to use a fluent Query Builder

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't know if no one knew or if it was just too silly to answer, but this is the correct statement:

`using StackExchange.Profiling.Helpers.Dapper;`

Comment: what nuget project you used to have that namespace? I am using Dapper & dapper.contrib. That namespace is not available.

Comment: Answer is obsolete

Comment: This answer is not correct. I fixed my original answer, as it has been 5 years since I posted it.

Answer (score 19):

This question appears in the dapper tutorial page, so I'm updating the answer.

In version 1.6, `SqlBuilder` is in the namespace `Dapper`. And it is included in the nuget package Dapper.SqlBuilder.

This is an example of how it works:

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();
builder.Select("id_something");
builder.Select("MyCol");
builder.Select("OtherCol");
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@MyParam", 3, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
builder.Where("id_something < @MyParam", parameters);
// builder.Where("id_something < @MyParam", new { MyParam =3}); //this is other option for params.
builder.InnerJoin("OtherTable on OtherTable.id=MyTable.id");
//The /**something**/ are placeholders,
var builderTemplate = builder.AddTemplate("Select /**select**/ from MyTable /**innerjoin**/ /**where**/ ");
var result = connection.Query<MyClass>(builderTemplate.RawSql, builderTemplate.Parameters);
```

This is the Sql generated:

```
Select id_something , MyCol , OtherCol
 from MyTable 
INNER JOIN OtherTable on OtherTable.id=MyTable.id
 WHERE id_something < @MyParam
```

Comment: Which Dapper tutorial page are you referring to?  I would like to read it.

Comment: Dapper had a tutorial page that linked to questions on stackoverflow. Not a real tutorial. I can´t find it again, probably changed it and now has this link https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/tag/sqlbuilder

Comment: @CarlosCuevas that's a not Dapper's Tutorial page. That's someone's attempt to hijack the library name and has absolutely no relation to Dapper itself. In fact, *bad* examples in that site cause headaches to the Dapper maintainers all the time.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>To this date, SqlBuilder has not made yet to any official package on Nuget. I got that installed by using the following package: Dapper.SqlBuilder. I really hope it becomes part of the official library.</strike>

Anyways, to your question, once the package is installed, you don't need to add any new "using" clause, as the SqlBuilder is inside the same Dapper namespace.

You can check the source code details in here: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.SqlBuilder/SqlBuilder.cs

EDIT:
The package can be found at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.SqlBuilder/

Comment: Comment is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called **[DapperQueryBuilder](https://github.com/Drizin/DapperQueryBuilder/)** which is an alternative to Dapper SqlBuilder, and the similar code from question above would be like this:

```cs
// using DapperQueryBuilder; ...

int myParam = 3;
var builder = cn.QueryBuilder();

builder.Select($"id_something");
builder.Select($"MyCol");
builder.Select($"OtherCol");
builder.From($"MyTable");
builder.From($"inner join OtherTable on OtherTable.id=MyTable.id");
builder.Where($"id_something < {myParam}");

var result = builder.Query<MyClass>();
```

Or even shorter if the only dynamic part is the filters:

```cs
var builder = cn.QueryBuilder($@""
    SELECT id_something, MyCol, OtherCol
    FROM MyTable
    inner join OtherTable on OtherTable.id=MyTable.id
    /**where**/
");

int myParam = 3;
builder.Where($"id_something < {myParam}");

var result = builder.Query<MyClass>();
```

Even though it looks like we're using unsafe interpolated strings, that's not true - **the output is fully parametrized SQL (`WHERE id_something < @p0`) - and you don't have to manually manage the dictionary of parameters** as you would do if using SqlBuilder.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library

Answer (score -4):

I did figure it out by making a new class file named SqlBuilder.cs and copied content from [THIS](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper.SqlBuilder/SqlBuilder.cs?r=c9160c13fb45eb512f66524825612397aa3728ba) link

Comment: Answer is obsolete