# Is there a nuget package that contains Dapper.Net SqlBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, dapper

I can't find a [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=dapper) package that contains [Dapper.Net SqlBuilder](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.SqlBuilder).

It's not in [Dapper dot net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/).
It's not in [DapperExtensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DapperExtensions/).
Its' not in [Dapper.Contrib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/).

Is there a nuget package available for Dapper.Net SqlBuilder?

Comment: There is now :-) ... https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.SqlBuilder/

Comment: Protip: you don't need "using Dapper.SqlBuilder", it is in the main Dapper namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was asked in 2014, and since 2015, the Nuget package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.SqlBuilder/

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.tritac.com/bp-24-dapper-net-by-example), [this](http://liangwu.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/dapper-net-tutorial-ii/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009550/how-to-use-sqlbuilder), you can't get it from NuGet. Just copy/download the file and add it to your project directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: https://github.com/ronnieoverby/uniquenamespace.sqlbuilder#installation

The body of the answer must be at least 30 characters.

Comment: This is not Dapper.Net SqlBuilder. Please make sure to mention it in your answer.

Comment: The truth is that it practically is. I changed the placeholder's from  `/**SELECT**/` to `{{SELECT}}`. That's the only real difference. Otherwise I copied they're code and made no other substantive interface changes.

Comment: Thank you for making AddClause() public!!

Comment: Nice work - any way to get this to work with the strong named Dapper package?